# cant get all ajax calls response in puppeteer page loading

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I have around four ajax calls on network tab while loading the url
[click here](https://chartink.com/screener/trend-trading-11)

but while scraping the data with puppetter , only one ajax call response url is being logged which is
https://chartink.com/screener/trend-trading-11

Here is the code which I have tried :-

```
async function main() {
  try {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    page.waitForResponse(async (response) => {
      console.log(response.url());
    });

    await page.goto("https://chartink.com/screener/trend-trading-11", {
      waitUntil: "networkidle0",
      timeout: 0,
    });

    await browser.close();
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
})();
```

Can anybody help on this?

Comment: timeout 0? doesn't it throw timeout in 0 seconds?

Comment: Actually i was getting some timeout errors while removing that

Comment: It works for me anyway. Your code.

Comment: so you are getting all four response url logged?

Comment: This is what I am getting: http://193.70.114.83/so.png

Comment: bro. there is some ajax calls going on document ready. you can see their request on network tab. what i need is the response from them

Comment: but these ajax calls are working, as it shows the result, what is your problem then?

Comment: check my scrapping code. I need these ajax calls response in my nodejs code

Comment: check my answer and take the final note as a clue on what to do

Comment: Sir is it legal to access or read Chartlink response as JSON?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is probably because you are using `async(response)`, this works for me:

```
...

const page = await browser.newPage();    
page.on('response', response => {
    response.text().then(function(textBody){ //this returns promise that ajax request body was received
        console.log(response.url());
        console.log(textBody);
    })
})    
await page.goto("https://chartink.com/screener/trend-trading-11", {
  waitUntil: "networkidle0",
  timeout: 0,
});
await browser.close();
```

The output bodies I get are from urls (won't paste the bodies content, as it is about 5MB):

```
https://chartink.com/screener/trend-trading-11
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.8.2/css/all.min.css
https://chartink.com/screener/trend-trading-11
https://chartink.com/js/lives_v2.js?id=439b7e42ac6b39972d7f
https://chartink.com/css/custom.css
https://chartink.com/css/font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.3/Chart.bundle.js
https://chartink.com/css/app.css?id=061148b114879e02aa12
https://chartink.com/css/bootstrap-tour.min.css
https://chartink.com/css/datatables.min.css
https://chartink.com/js/jquery.color.min.js
https://chartink.com/js/scan_filter.js?id=06e909b94080867f8291
https://chartink.com/js/bootstrap-tour-standalone.min.js
https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:300,400,600
https://chartink.com/js/app.js?id=9d30bc56db0d96b0b0b1
https://chartink.com/css/core.css
https://chartink.com/js/atlas.js?id=d575177318b1044bb512
https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js
https://chartink.com/images/bg.gif
https://chartink.com/images/new_header.png
https://chartink.com/images/search2.gif
https://chartink.com/images/white_line.png
https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js
https://chartink.com/css/jquery.timepicker.css
https://chartink.com/images/stats/add-circle.png
https://chartink.com/images/stats/operation.svg
https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/r20201001/r20190131/show_ads_impl.js
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.8.2/webfonts/fa-solid-900.woff2
https://www.google-analytics.com/j/collect?v=1&_v=j86&a=1793252394&t=pageview&_s=1&dl=https%3A%2F%2Fchartink.com%2Fscreener%2Ftrend-trading-11&ul=pl&de=UTF-8&dt=Trend%20trading%2C%20Technical%20Analysis%20Scanner&sd=24-bit&sr=1920x1080&vp=1903x927&je=0&_u=IEBAAEABAAAAAC~&jid=1026560667&gjid=1096229421&cid=1806703606.1602091906&tid=UA-19900447-1&_gid=339192360.1602091906&_r=1&_slc=1&z=1222043144
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.8.2/webfonts/fa-brands-400.woff2
https://chartink.com/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2
https://adservice.google.pl/adsid/integrator.js?domain=chartink.com
https://adservice.google.com/adsid/integrator.js?domain=chartink.com
https://www.googletagservices.com/activeview/js/current/osd.js?cb=%2Fr20100101
https://chartink.com/screener/process
https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/getconfig/sodar?sv=200&tid=gda&tv=r20201001&st=env
https://tpc.googlesyndication.com/sodar/sodar2.js
https://js-agent.newrelic.com/nr-1184.min.js
https://chartink.com/backtest/process
https://chartink.com/favicon.ico
https://chartink.com/manifest.json
https://chartink.com/favicon.ico
https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/gen_204?id=sodar2&v=217&t=2&li=gda_r20201001&jk=3868359323948220&bg=!7O-l7_dYuruaC6okFhkCAAAAyVIAAAAXCgB9K_NEuJ7yrGCy1lnOElRw5ctqJzVBPSfadY4e8WtxSMlAGizrMCBaK9b91_dCyeo9z0ksbtgGc2Dq6CAmznGnx9GpH7uehFc9h9mkiioPkpj8C4DSqq4AGPAmrpK6qTGaA55qMHXHa-PUMr-Q9iaXySa2BC1qGyefZ1em3EqZAeFac00sJYEhXkeg5Lf1Uvppw8eowhESkD63DFM10L46d72OnG2pdHC2fm6OjB8PvX-EpzJ2lbpbjpzVSzTfkayLP1Y1a7AfLkqE5kaREFCoa4w_VIwALi4CUXz5EuHD658HGZSv4ab6qiHf5c737JiKwyRASks71aAXAwOv8TNWjnEua25Mjqzk94-UPmzyW53PnMBJCsPx6ty1S9EU4pwa8EGwkXsyDV-uI26K4FHKZk-GOY4M5KQ9Wm5r1w13zd2JR4LfOfF146XC445aI6am77zwRBgKMJdWxgN6HHoYwGkX-EAPfl3_AHow0FPJoFQScpQmOxONhJf9L2pyCBZ8WwysF3gi28x_t3nMy8V38ld9IaQRp5k5I1yxGeUMGwdYT4IZ7lFGFh4s1Yr8xXYAAm5lF9zGP7VX-RXQd_LTsQZFKdjW8Wk4hdJUvl-rCy6qYJDQ8eKCnvESNSmDcywIucYYRaD_EvRBAoRevNp7lfVIQ9s5DMXUxWMrK576TLnymyK2hlzuJOBBUx2VqagT0TZhCAJcJXOhtyLXTuD1Ectp9j75IicdM9aYeOU0AScKay64n_wVCpificMRuLWyrQA4OnGF9WD6LLEIhWpjaQ5iXOaRuAVXvwGaosbukQaq
https://bam.nr-data.net/1/4f831ebbc0?a=375583170&v=1184.ab39b52&to=ZwYGbERVXkEAUEZQCV5MJVtCXV9cTkBRSwNVDQFK&rst=6423&ck=1&ref=https://chartink.com/screener/trend-trading-11&ap=348&be=1009&fe=5489&dc=3288&perf=%7B%22timing%22:%7B%22of%22:1602091902183,%22n%22:0,%22f%22:1,%22dn%22:26,%22dne%22:36,%22c%22:36,%22s%22:220,%22ce%22:432,%22rq%22:432,%22rp%22:968,%22rpe%22:1148,%22dl%22:987,%22di%22:3287,%22ds%22:3287,%22de%22:3295,%22dc%22:5488,%22l%22:5488,%22le%22:5498%7D,%22navigation%22:%7B%7D%7D&fp=2108&fcp=2108&at=S0ERGgxPTR5DUhADHU0e&jsonp=NREUM.setToken
```

**But be aware that it's easier to parse the output HTML than the raw responses. And that is the way I would take, to get the data.**

--

Comment: Thanks, that worked. the problem iam not scraping html for data is its datatabel and all need all the data instead of paginated datas. so i thought its better to took data from ajax call rather than clicking on each pagination button and scrapping data.
anyway its clientside pagination and there may be option to get all data in single go but i cant figure it out

Comment: why i cant get ajax calls when putting async there? 
beacuse inside that function i need to write  const responseData = response.json();

Comment: because response is an object, not a function, you can't make a promise like that, you can `await response.json()`, but not sure if the promise will not fail if it won't be a json; better would be to add something like `if response.json() ...` to my function, if it got text, it got json as well, if it is a json.

Comment: Sir is it legal to access or read Chartlink response as JSON?

Comment: what do you mean?